# UPDATETIME not working in phpMyAdmin with YII

Tags: php, yii

```
`createdtime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

if I manually update the values in phpMyAdmin it works fine.but updating through yii its not working.its just shows me CreatedTime.

Comment: Can you post the code? At least post the rules of the class' and the controller part when you assign te value and save.

Answer (score 0):

I got answer.just need to add

```
'setOnEmpty'=>false,
```

in model